# Expand wildcard path (like shell)

Tags: c++

How can I easily expand a string like `images/*` into a list of the files in that folder? Similar to if I were to pass that as an argument to `main` and have the shell expands it.

EDIT: I am wondering if there is a nicer way than manually iterating the directory. Also something cross platform.

Comment: On a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) you could use the [`glob`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html) function.

Comment: has to be cross platform, i suppose something in boost, but id rather not add another dependency

Comment: Did you already check `boost::filesystem`? You can easily build up that feature based on `path` iterators.

Comment: What are you going to do with the list of files? If you're going to read them, you'll have to iterate over each of them.